# Does C# have a generic equivalent of Java's Class<T>?

Tags: java, c#

In Java, `Class<T>` is generic, which is useful if I want a constrained parameter; for example:

```
public void foo(Class<? extends Comparable<?>> clazz) {
    ...
}

foo(Integer.class) // OK!
foo(Object.class) // Error - does not implement Comparable<?>
```

C#'s equivalent is `Type`, but it's not generic, meaning you can't constrain parameters; for example:

```cs
public void Foo(Type clazz) {
    ...
}

Foo(typeof(int)) // OK!
Foo(typeof(object)) // OK!
```

I guess one solution could be to pass the type as a generic parameter; for example:

```cs
public void Foo<T>() where T : IComparable<T> {
    typeof(T)
}

Foo<int>() // OK!
Foo<object>() // Error - does not implement IComparable<T>
```

Is this the only approach, or is there something more equivalent to the Java approach, in other words is there something like `Type<T>` in C#?

Comment: That's the only way. What's wrong with this approach? To me (knowing both Java and C#) your first and last examples look functionally the same.

Comment: C# generics are reified; it's a templating system. In java they are not, it's a compiler-checked-documentation system. As a consequence, a ton of generic-specific stuff is completely different between C# and Java. Separately, the fact that java's `j.l.Class` is genericsed is mostly an error that can no longer be fixed. There are things generics can represent that a class cannot (`such as `List<String>`), and things classes can represent that generics can't (such as `int.class`).

Comment: @Jesse: Probably nothing wrong in this specific example (actually I am intrigued by that solution). But unfortunately, I don't see how to emulate return types of Class<? extends...> with a similar construct in C#, right?

Answer (score 4):

`Foo<T>()` approach is the only one in C#.

Java approach is a workaround for compile-time-only (type erasure) generics.

Comment: This. Using a `Class`, which predates generics by years, is often used as workaround. That's simply not needed in C#, because it can read the generic type during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `public Foo<T>(T inputParam) where T: IComparable, new()` and limit the type of generic `inputParam`. However, you can only limit it by an interface and not by class. [More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)